# Property of summation

Tags: summation

Very short question. Could you please explain me why

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a = na$$
with $a$ a constant? 
I know that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a = na$$

but in my case the sum starts from zero and finishes for $(n-1)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out what is difficult to understand here. Can you enlighten me ?

Comment: Recognize that $\{0,1,2,3,4,\dots,n-1\}$ has $n$ elements in it.  If this is not immediately obvious why, then recognize that it has the $n-1$ positive elements $\{1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ and also the one additional zero element $\{0\}$.  It follows that your summation is iterated a total of $n$ times (*the one time when the index is zero, and then the following $n-1$ times while the index is positive for a total of $1+(n-1)=n$ times*).

Comment: Thanks JMoravitz, your rationale was what I needed to convince myself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In both cases – $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a\quad \text { and }\quad\sum_{i=1}^{n}a$$

– there are exactly $n$ summands.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Since you are already convinced that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a=na$ this might help:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a={a}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a=a+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a-{a}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a.$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $a$ is not $i$-depending one can write: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a}=a\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{1}$$ 
And $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{1}=1+1+\cdots+1$ $n$ times which obviously is $n$.

Answer (score 2):

What is the definition of $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x_i$? It is exactly $x_0+x_1+...x_{n-1}$. If $x_0=x_1=...x_{n-1}=a$ then it means you just sum $a$ $n$ times. And that gives $na$.

Answer (score 1):

You are summing $n$ terms, all equal to $a$. So
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a = a+ a+\dotsb + a = na.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$a$ times the number of terms.